# Vue Could not trigger child component function

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, vue.js

I have a child component `selectServiceChargeComponent` inside a parent component (Saving Invoice Component). Child component is simply a form inside a table. If clicked on add row button new row would be formed. Problem is when I click on add row button, the following error arises:

[image: Error photo]

After looking some SO answers, I found `ref` would help to trigger a function in child component. So, in parent's component I used a `ref` inside child component and create a add row button underneath it and tried to trigger a click function `addRow()`.

So that I could use `this.$refs.serviceChargeComponent.addRow();`.
But another problem came in return.

[image: 2nd problem]

[image: child Component ref]

[image: Updated Pic]

Comment: It seems addRow isn't defined in your child component. Can you share your child component's code.

Comment: sure, it's updated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like addRow() function is outside of methods:{}. Methods in vue should be defined inside methods: {}.